# time Complexity in Recursion

Tags: c, recursion, time-complexity

I need help with this code..how can I improve the time complexity of the following recursion? Do I need to remove the recursion at all? Because in that case my code is giving variable results when I am trying with for/while loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int one=0,zero=0;
void reco(int n)
{
    if(n<=0)
    {
        zero++;
        return;
    }
    if(n==1)
    {
        one++;
        return;
    }
    reco(n-1);
    reco(n-2);
    reco(n-3);
    return;

}
main()
{   int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    reco(n);
    printf("%d %d",one,zero);
    return;
}
```

input:7
Output: 24 33

Comment: What exactly is your function attempting to do?

Comment: I got this question in the second round of job interview and I was asked to improve the code because the compiler would say "terminated due to time out" for large input...and I am trying to figure out how to improve it

Comment: straightforward way is to cache numbers of ones and zeros added by every subproblem `reco(i)` so that they are not recomputed again

Comment: @mangusta's approach would be described as **dynamic programming** with **memoization**.

Comment: we may go bottom up if we notice that the lowest possible subproblem is `reco(-1)`

Comment: Now I get it ! will give it a try

Comment: I think the easiest optimization is to understand what the problem is doing. Looks like reco(10) will call internally reco(9) reco (8) and reco(7). Each of those will repeat some version of itself so you want to remove the duplication, so what is the best way?

Comment: It is also a linear homogeneous recurrent relation which can be solved mathematically as the sum of 3 power-n terms, but I guess you'd better look on http://math.stackexchange.com/ for that.